Сохранения Blender в Fedora и Flatpak
Сделал сохранение в Blender установленный через Steam, сама программа прекрасно видит свои сохранённые файлы но вот система через свой проводник и через терминал "ls" видеть сохранения не хотят, подсказали что файл сохранён в Flatpak, почитал о нём пару статей но так и не понял как удалить эти сохранения, также попробовал снести стимовский Blender и поставить из центра приложений, Blender оттуда уже делал сохранения куда мне надо не используя Flatpak но вот вопрос что делать с теми сохранениями и как взаимодействовать лично с Flatpаk?

Для таких вопросов есть форум "Blender"
